# how to post values in cakephp 2.x and show the filtered records in another page

Tags: cakephp

I have designed page in cakephp contains form which input filed name 'id' and submit button. I want to display the data filtered by the 'id' in view page. Please give me an example with code for this.

Answer (score 1):

So you wanna search into a database for this ID and return back all stored data to the view?

First of all,you have to retrieve your data. See here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html
Secondly, you have to use 
`$this->set('var_name', $var_name_containing_found_data);`
and finally you can handle your data into the view by manipulating as you wish the `$var_name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put this action in your controller:

```
    public function your_action($id = null) {//your action
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $search = $this->YourModel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $this->request->data['id'])));//assuming id is submitted like you said $_POST['id']
$this->set('search', $search);
}
    }
```

You can access the search variable in your view (your_view.ctp) like this `$this->search`

assuming your cakephp version is 2.x

Comment: thanks now how to display data from mysql in view page

Comment: If it helps, you please vote up and select the answer, thanks